# Java HSQLDB connection issue

Tags: java, hsqldb

I have been making a program that is using HSQL to connect to a database that I created. For some reason some methods in my class can call on the database and perform commands, while other parts cannot. I keep getting this error,

**java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: feature not supported**

and here is the method,

```
public List<CustomerInfo> DBgetInfo(String Customer)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlConnection, userId,
            password);
    Statement stmt= con.createStatement();



    String query = "SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.CUSTOMER";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


    rs.first(); //The error happens on this line


    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();

}
```

I have ran the debugger multiple times and there error is in this method on the rs.first line. I have tried remaking the DB, reimporting all the files, checking to make sure the command is correct, and ect... The weird thing is that earlier in this class I have a method very similar to this, but it has no issues. I really can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCResultSet.html#first()) this error occurs:

> Throws:
>   SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed result set or the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
>   SQLFeatureNotSupportedException - if the JDBC driver does not support this method

Earlier on the same page, there is a section on HSQL specific details for result sets.  To call `first` you need to modify your statement creation:

> ResultSet object generated by HSQLDB is by default of ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY (as is standard JDBC behavior) and does not allow the use of absolute and relative positioning methods. If a statement is created with:
>
> Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
>
> then the ResultSet objects it produces support using all of the absolute and relative positioning methods of JDBC2 to set the position of the current row...

But you might want to think about why you need to call `first`.